# Traduction : "We have thought about it." (y ou ça/cela)

Tags: traduction, pronoms

Comment faut-il traduire :

> We have thought about it.

?

> Nous avons pensé/réfléchi à ça/cela.

ou

> Nous y avons pensé/réfléchi.

Je trouve la deuxième proposition plus correcte mais je me demande si l'on peut utiliser également la première. Le cas échéant, y a-t-il des différences entre les deux interprétations ?

Comment: Aucune différence

Comment: La même qu'entre *it* et *this* (ou *that*)…

Comment: A l'oral, on entendra surtout *on y a pensé*.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre on y a pensé et on y a réfléchi ?

Comment: Oui, une petite différence.

Comment: *On y a pensé* : on a pensé à faire quelque chose qu'il ne fallait pas oublier et on l'a fait. *On y a réfléchi* : on a pensé de manière approfondie à quelque chose (un problème), le résultat de cette réflexion n'est pas précisé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux sont acceptables, mais

> Nous y avons pensé

me semble mieux/plus fluide en tant que structure de phrase. Dépendemment du contexte,

> Nous l'avons considéré

peut aussi être utilisé.